# In Eclipse, how do I load php files from outside of WebContent folder to outside of context root?

Tags: php, eclipse, tomcat

I have the following php files in an include folder outside of the WebContent folder of my dynamic web project:

[image: Include folder]

But when deploying the Website project to the Apache Tomcat 8 server instance, the server only deploys the files in WebContent folder to the context root "/".

Is there a some sort of server configuration that will automatically map and deploy all the files from the include folder oustide the Webcontent folder to a folder outside of the context root (so there would be an include folder in the following picture)?

[image]